# Missing "close friends" notifications using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications

When requesting the /me/notifications connection for a user, I used to also get notifications associated with the "close friends" list, as long as of course the user enabled them on the website (which is the default anyway). Now, although I can see unread notifications in the browser coming from a close friend, such notifications do not appear in the notifications connection anymore. I though of a changed permission and so added read_friendlists to the permissions of my app, since in the past I noticed some notifications did not appear in the API unless you had some specific permission (although the documentation only talks about manage_notifications), but nothing changed.

Do you know what may be the cause?